# Build a k-ary tree with no repeated values

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose I have two values: `x1` and `x2`.

Given a single root, how to build all the combinations of `x1` and `x2` using an k-ary tree?

Example:

```
#0    root
      /   \
#1  x1     x2
     |
#2  x2
```

At level `#1` I have the initial elements, `x1` and `x2`.

At level `#2` I  have `x2`, making the combination `x1x2`, but don't have `x1` because it would be a **repeated** combination (`x2x1`, we don't care about the elements order here).

If I had more than two elements, the tree would keep going on, until the level is equal to the number of elements minus 1.

I have already built the initial `#1` level. but how do I keep generating the tree without repeating combinations? In other words, how to **verify** if I should or not put a given element on the tree, in the most performatic way. There is some well-known algorithm for this?

Additional info: PHP

Comment: What is the task that you want to accomplish? To list all combinations of a set of elements irrespective of order? Do you really have to use k-ary tree?

Comment: @justhalf Yes,  to list all combinations of a set of elements irrespective of order. I don't have to use trees, but it's the first thing came to my mind.

Comment: Then I think you should ask that question instead. I think trees might not be a good solution for this. The usual solution is using recursion, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695772/generating-k-combinations-lexicographically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: some modifications on building the tree**

My idea is having a n-ary tree for n elements `(x1, x2,... ,xn)`. let root be `x0`, then for any node `xi` `(0 <= i <= n)`, you should have all children `xj` where `(i < j <= n)`. In this way you can have all non-repeating combinations. E.g. for n=3 the 3-ary tree would be something like this:

```
root ---> x1 ---> x2 ---> x3
          |  ---> x3
root ---> x2 ---> x3
root ---> x3
```